# Linear algebra: diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L: P_2 \longrightarrow P_2$ be the linear operator defined by $L(p(t)) = p'(t)$ for $p(t) \in P_2$, the space of real polynomials of degree at most $2$. Is $L$ diagonalizable? If it is, find a basis $S$ for $P_2$ with respect to which $L$ is represented by a diagonal matrix.

Answer: $L$ is not diagonalizable. The eigenvalues of $L$ are $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$. The set of associated eigenvectors does not form a basis for $P_2$.

I don't how you solve this problem. How do you transform the polynomial into a matrix so that I can find the eigenvalues? I can solve these questions if they state the matrix but this one concerns polynomials. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Pick a basis of $P_2$. What is the standard basis?
2. Write the matrix of $L$ with respect to that basis (you'll have to apply $L$ to each element of the basis of $P_2$, and calculate its coordinates in that basis; that'll give you the columns of the matrix).
3. Work with the matrix now: is it diagonalizable?

---

1.

> We can choose the basis $B = \{1, x, x^2\}$.

2.

> $L(1) = 1' = 0 = 0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 \\ L(x) = x' = 1 = 1 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 \\ L(x^2) = (x^2)' = 2x = 0 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 \\ \text{Then} \\ \left[L\right]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 2  \\ 0 & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$

3.

> Find the roots of $\det(xI - \left[L\right]_B)$, which will be the eigenvalues, and the corresponding eigenvectors. Do you end up with a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Would it be the same if I had the basis in the reverse order, {$t^{2}$, t, 1} and the matrix ended up being $\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 2 & 0&0 \\ 0&1&0\end{matrix}$ ?

Comment: @Ashley You would have a different matrix representation of $L$, but the matrix representation is just that, a *representation*. It temporarily enables you to work with real numbers, as if you had a linear transformation $\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$, forgetting for a moment that in fact it was $P_2 \to P_2$. But it doesn't matter which basis you pick; as long as you do your calculations correctly, you'll end up with the same answer.

Comment: I see. But what does it mean in the answer that "The set of associated eigenvectors does not form a basis for P2"? Didn't I just form a basis for P2? Sorry for asking a lot of questions

Comment: @Ashley Yes, you formed a basis for $P_2$, which is completely necessary to solve the problem. $P_2$ certainly *has* a basis (in fact, lots of them). However, the linear transformation will be diagonalizable if and only if its eigenvectors *also* contain a basis of $P_2$. You now have to calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix, and see what their associated eigenvectors are; and then see if these eigenvectors are enough to form a basis (independently of the basis you considered earlier, which was just used to do the calculations, and has no inference in whether $L$ is diagonalizable).

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks so much for your help talmid :)

Comment: @talmid No problem. There's one extra thing you should know: since you're working with the matrix, you'll get the eigenvectors in $\Bbb R^3$, but remember that $L$ was $P_2 \to P_2$, so in order to know the *real* eigenvectors of $L$ you'll have to convert back to $P_2$ using the basis you considered. For example, suppose you choose the basis $\{x^2, x, 1\}$, and by calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\left[L\right]_B$ you get that $3$ is an eigenvalue with associated eigenvector $(1,2,5)$. This is an eigenvector of $\left[L\right]_B$, not of $L$. We convert back to $P_2$ using $B$...

Comment: ... and we get that the eigenvector is $1 \cdot x^2 + 2 \cdot x + 5 \cdot 1 = x^2 + 2x + 5$, which makes sense since it's an element of $P_2$, unlike $(1,2,5)$. However, if all you want to know is whether $L$ is diagonalizable, it's enough to consider the set of eigenvectors of $\left[L\right]_B$ (those in $\Bbb R^3$) and see if it's a basis of $\Bbb R^3$, because if it is, then we know for sure that converting to $P_2$ through $B$ will give us a basis of $P_2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks. I got mixed up. Fixed it. And for completeness, the eigenvalues of $\left[L\right]_B$ and $L$ will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to pick your favorite basis for $P_2$; this will allow you to find a matrix for $L$. Then you can use the standard techniques once you have a matrix representation for $L$.

Now, *my* favorite basis for $P_2$ (which I am guessing from context is all polynomials of degree at most $2$; careful, as sometimes it means the set of polynomial of degree *less than* $2$), absent countervailing influences, is $\beta=\{1,x,x^2\}$. How does $L$ behave relative to this basis?

$$\begin{align*}
L(1) &= (1)' = 0\\
&= 0(1) + 0(x) + 0(x^2);\\
L(x) &= (x)' = 1\\
&= 1(1) + 0(x) + 0(x^2);\\
L(x^2) &= (x^2)' = 2x\\
&= 0(1) + 2(x) + 0(x^2).
\end{align*}$$
So the matrix that represents $L$ with respect to the basis $\beta$, $[L]_{\beta}^{\beta}$, is
$$[L]_{\beta}^{\beta} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
(the first column is the $\beta$-coordinate vector of $L(1)$; the second column is the $\beta$-coordinate vector of $L(x)$; and the third column is the $\beta$-coordinate vector of $L(x^2)$).

The characteristic polynomial of $L$ is the same as the characteristic polynomial of any of its matrix representations, and the eigenvalues of $L$ are the eigenvalues of $[L]_{\beta}^{\beta}$.

Can you go from here?